# How to resolve an async issue

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity

Firstly, let me preface by saying I am not a developer by any means. I have a tiny coding background which I'm attempting to rely on here, but its failing me.

My problem is as follows:

I have some code which is basically a bot that performs jobs on the ethereum network for smart contracts. The code is entirely in javascript so the blockchain aspect of what I'm attempting to do is immaterial. But basically I am trying to perform an API request which receives a number (called "gas") this number determines how much my bot is willing to pay in order to perform a job on the ethereum network. However, I've learned the default number the API sends is too low. So I've decided to try and increase the gas by multiplying the number gotten from the API request. However when I do that, it seems the code tried multiplying the number before it receives the API request. Consequently, I receive a NaN error. The original code looks like the following:

```
    async work() {
        this.txPending = true;
        try {
          const gas = await this.getGas();
          const tx = await this.callWork(gas);
          this.log.info(`Transaction hash: ${tx.hash}`);
          const receipt = await tx.wait();
          this.log.info(`Transaction confirmed in block ${receipt.blockNumber}`);
          this.log.info(`Gas used: ${receipt.gasUsed.toString()}`);
        } catch (error) {
          this.log.error("While working:" + error);
        }
        this.txPending = false;
      }
```

The changes I make look like the following:

```
    async work() {
    this.txPending = true;
    try {
      let temp_gas = await this.getGas();
      const gas = temp_gas * 1.5;
      const tx = await this.callWork(gas);
      console.log(gas);
      console.log('something');
      const receipt = await tx.wait();
      this.log.info(`Transaction confirmed in block ${receipt.blockNumber}`);
      this.log.info(`Gas used: ${receipt.gasUsed.toString()}`);
    } catch (error) {
      this.log.error("While working:" + error);
    }
    this.txPending = false;
  }
```

From my research, it seems what I need to do is create a promise function, but I am absolutely lost on how to go about creating this. If anyone could help me, I'd be willing to pay them a bit of ethereum maybe .2 (roughly $150).

Comment: Sorry, what's the difference between the 2 pieces of code?

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you can not determine the gas cost of the transaction, but immediately set some rather large value for gas, for example, 0x400000. The miner will take from this amount as much as necessary, and leave the excess on your account. This is the difference between Ethereum and Bitcoin - in Bitcoin the entire specified fee will be taken by the miner.

Comment: Sorry, I realized posted the wrong snippet for the second one. 

Anyway, I thought the way gas worked was that if you put some arbitrary large number it wouldn't take all of it, but would still take a good bit more than necessary. 

Btw, this is the API I'm pulling from:  "https://www.gasnow.org/api/v3/gas/price?utm_source=relayerjobs"

So, as you can see it generates some gas cost that it thinks will work. But due to competition amongts the other guys trying to do the same thing as me, its usually not enough. So I've tried making the changes I posted.